# How and why did Pam kiss fake-Jim in the Asian-Jim prank in The Office?

Tags: the-office

In the S9E3 "Andy’s Ancestry", Jim pulls an epic prank on Dwight where Jim's Asian actor friend Steve comes to the office and tricks Dwight into thinking he is Jim. Not surprisingly, Dwight is somewhat convinced too.

> Dwight: You don't work here! You're not Jim!
>   Pam: Jim, I got us that dinner reservation. Grico’s at 7:30.
>   Fake Jim: Oh great, can't wait.
>   [Kisses Pam]

Kisses Pam? Really? Did he really kiss his friend's wife JUST to prove to Dwight that he really is Jim? Did Pam really go with the kiss without feeling awkward and bizarre? I mean he is a friend ... NOT her husband.

How and why did they kiss, even as a prank?

Comment: I don't really see a question here. They kissed, she knew about the prank, what's the problem?

Comment: I think this question is really about a difference between how important and meaningful a kiss is. For many people, kissing someone who isn’t your husband is not a big deal, especially if there’s some reason for it and your husband doesn’t mind. Remember that professional actors kiss and perform sex scenes with people who are not their spouses all the time.  Also, Pam had to lean down to miss fake Jim. I feel the script excerpt you quoted has the agency backward. She kisses him, not the other way around.

Comment: ^See now that was my actual question. Cultural difference may be, but I wanted to know how and why the character husband was fine with his wife kissing his friend. I guess It is inappropriate in some cultures, not a big deal in others.

Comment: It’s clearly not a big deal to Jim and Pam, as we can see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it was just a short smooch, not a long, passionate, french kiss, so doing it only for a prank on Dwight would not be that bad. Also, Jim and Pam really love each other and there is trust in their relationship, so what would be wrong with a prank like this? In some families, groups of friends, cultures and so on, a kiss like that, or on the cheeck is a normal way of greeting.